# Correct a test in a bash script, to echo only if every file found meets the specified test condition

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
for x in $(ls -ll <path to files> | awk '{ print $3,$4 }' | tail -n +2) ; do 
  if [ "${x}" != "root" ] ; then
    echo "Fail"
    break
  else
    echo "Pass"
 fi
done
```

Now, this prints "Pass" for every file it finds. I want to print "Pass" if **all** files are owned by *root*, and print "Fail" if **any** user or group in list is not *root*.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to find out if all files in your  are owned by root and belong to group root, use find:

```
find <path to files> ! -user root -or ! -group root -print
```

If anything is returned, that file either is not owned by root, or does not belong to the group root.  You can then put that into a conditional clause to print out Pass or Fail.

```
[[ "$(find <path to files> ! -user root -or ! -group root -print)" == "" ]] && echo "Pass" || echo "Fail"
```

Comment: possibly with a "-maxdepth 1" if recursion isn't desired

Answer (score 5):

First, you shouldn't parse the output of `ls` and its variations. You can go about this using `stat`:

```
$ stat -c%U-%G ./*
tomasz-tomasz
tomasz-tomasz
tomasz-tomasz
```

As you can see, the result is a reliable list of two words concatenated, which you can operate on to get the result wanted. Put it into a loop, and there you go:

```
PASS=true
for i in $(stat -c%U-%G ./*); do
    if ! [[ "$i" == root-root ]]; then
        PASS=false; break
    fi
done
if "$PASS"; then
    echo Pass
else
    echo Fail
fi
```

The value of `i` needs to be `root-root` for the loop to get to its end with the switch unchanged.

Replace `./*` with `the_dir/*` to test another location.

The `-` separator is needed, because, as Grump noted in the comments, *The string comparison may fail if the file is owned by 'roo' and in the group 'troot', so a separator would still be a good thing.*

Familiarise yourself with this: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead)

Comment: the hyphen `-` is a poor choice of separator since it is a legal character in usernames on at least some systems; the colon `:` is a better choice and it's what `chown` uses too

Comment: @kbolino But if there's one hyphen in one username, there would be two total in the product of `%U-%G`, while `root-root` has only one. So they would not be equal.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't think groups can be named the empty string.

Comment: Actually, empty group name wouldn't matter at all. The only case where the hyphen would be a problem is where the user name you're *looking for* has a hyphen as then user john-smith in group users would be indistinguishable from user john in group smith-users. The practical relevance of this exception is pretty low, though.

Comment: @kbolino Agreed.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I think this stat solution is what I am looking for. Does anyone see an issue at adding "2> /dev/null" to the end of the line? The unfortunate part of my task is that this is part of  larger script to check for compliance and there are cases where this set of files must be checked for root ownership, but they might not exist on all hosts. My next approach would be to add a conditional statement in there for if file exists

Comment: @CalebHoch At the end of which line? If you want to get rid of the errors for `stat`, then place it inside the substitution, ie. `$(stat -c%U-%G ./* 2>/dev/null)`. But better first check if there's anything to stat or adjust your script's logic. Also be careful with hidden files like `.sth`, as `./*` doesn't catch them. You need `./.*` for them.

Comment: @Tomasz I found where the error was. When i was testing the command by itself to see the output, I Used sudo. I accidentally copied that into my script with sudo so it was printing a "Last login" line. Initially I just used grep-v "Last Login" because I thought it might be some system specific reason it was doing that, but then i removed sudo from the script and it began working. Thanks for the help! This is perfect. Im definitely going to read that link you posted too.

Comment: @CalebHoch Good. Whatever you end up with, remember to test against an empty directory to check your logic.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
[ 1 = $({ echo root:root; stat -c"%U:%G" *; } | sort -u | wc -l) ] && echo PASS || echo FAIL
```

**EDIT:**  or

```
[ -z $(stat -c"%U:%G" * | grep -vm1 root:root) ] && echo PASS || echo FAIL
```

Comment: Smart, but a short-circuit break after the first fail is a big optimisation.

Comment: Admitted. Added another approach that quits after first non-match.

Comment: Non-match of what? Is it not the same thing?

Comment: `grep`'s  `-m1` option makes it leave after the first match (due to the `-v`: non-match), i.e. the first line not matching "root:root".

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is probably

```
found=$(find <path to files> -maxdepth 1 -not \( -user root -group root \) -printf "x")
found=${found:+Fail}
echo ${found:=Pass}
```

However, the simplest way of altering your script is:

```
found="Pass"

for x in $(ls -llA <path to files> | awk 'FNR>2{ print $3,$4 }' )
do 
   if [ "${x}" != "root" ]
   then
       found="Fail"
       break
   fi
done

echo $found
```

here I've added the A flag to catch files that begin with a "."

Doing it this way, however, is not a good idea as filenames containing a newline will cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `ls` is risky in command lines. I suggest using `find` for this purpose in the shellscript.

- The parameters to `find -printf` are described in `man find`.
- The standard output is piped to `grep` and the exit status is stored in `norootfile`.
- The output is also written to a temporary file, and the number of lines is counted and stored in `numfile` (the number of files found).
- You can use the option `-v` 'verbose' to get more details in the output from the shellscript.

If you want to search also hidden files use `find .` instead of `find *`

If you don't want to search in subdirectories, use `-maxdepth 1` in the find command line.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "-h" ]
then
 echo "Usage: $0 -h  # this help text"
 echo "       $0 -v  # verbose output"
 exit
fi

tmpfil=$(mktemp)

find * -xtype f -printf "%u:%g  %p\n" | tee "$tmpfil" | grep -v '^root:root' > /dev/null

norootsfile=$?
numfile=$(wc -l "$tmpfil")
#cat "$tmpfil"

if [ ${numfile%% *} -eq 0 ]
then
 echo "No file found; check the current directory"
elif [ $norootsfile -eq 0 ]
then
 echo "Fail"
 if [ "$1" == "-v" ]
 then
  echo "----- Found some file(s) not owned or grouped by root"
  echo "user:group file-name --------------------------------"
  grep -v '^root:root' "$tmpfil"
 fi
else
 echo "Pass"
 if [ "$1" == "-v" ]
 then
  echo "----- Found only files owned or grouped by root"
 fi
fi
rm "$tmpfil"
```